# terra R package resample of non-empty raster by 'sum' produces empty raster

Tags: raster, resampling, terra

I have a raster x which is at a resolution of 100m and pixel value is its area in sqkm is suitable for an action, see below

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 769, 716, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent      : 7877150, 7948750, 2413700, 2490600  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) 
source      : 15951_oppaoh.tif 
name        :        area 
min value   : 0.008644464 
max value   : 0.008644755
```

I want to produce a raster y, with dimensions 10km (10,000m) such that the pixel value is the sum of the pixel values of x i.e. pixel value of y is the total area (sqkm) in 10x10km pixel suitable for an action.

So I created a 'mask' raster which is of resolution 10,000m and same projection as x, with values 1:number of pixels in it (which does not mean anything)

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 333, 325, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
extent      : 7590450, 10840450, 902100, 4232100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) 
source      : raster10km_mask.tif 
name        :  lyr.1 
min value   :    107 
max value   : 108007
```

I have done

```
y<- terra::resample(x, mask raster, method= "sum")
```

The y that I receive is empty when I clearly have pixels in the original raster.

How can I calculate y?

(I have the developmental version of terra based on another stack exchange post that I cannot find and link currently)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "is empty"? Here I try to reproduce your question.

These are your input rasters

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=769, ncol=716, res=100, crs="EPSG:3857",
     ext=c(7877150, 7948750, 2413700, 2490600))
x <- rast(nrow=333, ncol=325, res=10000, crs="EPSG:3857", 
     ext=c(7590450, 10840450, 902100, 4232100))

# assign some values to `r` 
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
```

This shows something...

```
z <- resample(r, y, "sum")
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 8, 8, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 10000, 10000  (x, y)
#extent      : 7870450, 7950450, 2412100, 2492100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857) 
#source      : memory 
#name        :      lyr.1 
#min value   :  944575040 
#max value   : 4468296704 

# and so does
plot(z)
```

Since `x` covers much more area than `r`, you may want to zoom in to better see what is going on

```
y <- crop(x, r, "out")
values(r) <- 1
zz <- resample(r, y, "sum")

plot(as.lines(y), mar=c(3,3,3,7))
plot(zz, add=T, col="light blue")
lines(ext(r), col="red", lwd=3)
lines(y)
```

[image]

If you want to also get a sum for the large cells of `x` that are partly outside of `r` you can first extend `r` a bit

```
rr <- extend(r, crop(x, r, "out")) 
zzz <- resample(rr, y, "sum")
plot(zzz)
lines(ext(r), col="red", lwd=3)
lines(y)
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that my mask raster aka 10km covers a much wider area than the given fine resolution raster x. I followed your suggestions but I am not sure I follow. y <- crop(maskraster, fine resolution raster, "out") is fine, but why do you then make all the values of the fine resolution raster 1 and then resample?